# Why does import <package> not work ,but import <package.submodule> work?

Tags: python, import, module, attributes, attributeerror

I am trying to use a python package called `nilearn`, but I think this issue could occur more generally, and I'm just trying to understand WHY this happens. I'd really appreciate any further references that could help me understand what's going on at a deeper level.

The very first instructions in the [intro nilearn tutorial](https://nilearn.github.io/stable/introduction.html) are

```
import nilearn
print(nilearn.datasets.MNI152_FILE_PATH)
```

If I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'nilearn' has no attribute 'datasets'
```

However, if I try the following code, everything works

```
import nilearn.datasets
print(nilearn.datasets.MNI152_FILE_PATH)
```

Clearly, `nilearn` does have a submodule called `datasets`. Why am I not able to use it when I just `import nilearn`.

More broadly, is this behavior specific to `nilearn`, or does it occur more broadly across python packages? What exactly is going on?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, when you import something, you import just that module. `nilearn` is a module, `nilearn.datasets` is another. By importing `nilearn`, you are just importing that module (which does not include the `nilearn.datasets` submodule), not the `nilearn.datasets` module.

If you were to do

```
from nilearn import *
```

You would get the `nilearn.datasets` module because when using `*` in an import statement, you are importing every module within, and therefore the `nilearn.datasets`.

Alternatively you could also do:

```
from nilearn import nilearn.datasets
```

If you just wanted this submodule.

Answer (score -1):

This is not specific to nilearn.
This usually happens when is  module is defined like this

```
  module_name/
       __init__.py
       submodule.py
```

Here we can't import module_name and use module_name.submodule.This throws error.
We have to import like `import module_name.submodule`

You can learn more about importing in python and difference between module and package.
[How do import work in python?](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)